# Heruku App Push SQLite error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, postgresql, heroku, web-deployment

I have configured PostgreSQL on my development. 
Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'

gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'

gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
```

Here is my database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: first_development
  pool: 5
  username: first
  password: first
  host: localhost

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: first_test
  pool: 5
  username: first
  password: first
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: dbn3r3qugr8bac
  pool: 5
  username: mztnrqbzratihw
  password: RyWmeSr9gP3tj8THsGYe63G46T
  timeout: 5000
```

Here is heroku config:

```
flashbag@netbook:~/rails/first$ heroku config
=== calm-castle-9869 Config Vars
DATABASE_URL:               postgres://mztnrqbzratihw:RyWmeSr9gP3tj8THsGYe63G46T@ec2-54-235-99-46.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dbn3r3qugr8bac
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_NAVY_URL: postgres://dhxbjccraaarir:yCJTHCZ6gcj-5o8gdD3U5oJDoh@ec2-54-235-99-46.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d19qqi2rfrsmmo
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED_URL:  postgres://mztnrqbzratihw:RyWmeSr9gP3tj8THsGYe63G46T@ec2-54-235-99-46.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dbn3r3qugr8bac
```

And here is rake output:

```
flashbag@netbook:~/rails/first$ rake db:setup
-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
   (55.9ms)  CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" character varying(255) NOT NULL) 
   (62.0ms)  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "unique_schema_migrations" ON "schema_migrations" ("version")
   -> 0.2765s
   (2.3ms)  SELECT version FROM "schema_migrations"
   (7.0ms)  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('0')
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (2.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
flashbag@netbook:~/rails/first$ rake db:migrate
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (2.9ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
```

But I can't push my app to heroku, it's always:

```
flashbag@netbook:~/rails/first$ git push heroku master
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 80, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (67/67), done.
Writing objects: 100% (80/80), 189.40 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 80 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.5.2
       New app detected loading default bundler cache
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
       Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Using minitest (4.7.5)
       Using atomic (1.1.14)
       Using tzinfo (0.3.38)
       Using builder (3.1.4)
       Using erubis (2.7.0)
       Using rack (1.5.2)
       Installing multi_json (1.8.4)
       Using polyglot (0.3.3)
       Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
       Using arel (4.0.1)
       Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
       Using execjs (2.0.2)
       Using thor (0.18.1)
       Using hike (1.2.3)
       Using json (1.8.1)
       Installing mime-types (1.25.1)
       Using bundler (1.5.2)
       Using tilt (1.4.1)
       Installing i18n (0.6.9)
       Using rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
       Installing rake (10.1.1)
       Installing rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.2)
       Using thread_safe (0.1.3)
       Using rack-test (0.6.2)
       Using treetop (1.4.15)
       Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Installing uglifier (2.1.1)
       Using rdoc (3.12.2)
       Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
       /tmp/build_3e5ff6a8-f774-4699-b590-b197eacde04d/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       checking for sqlite3.h... no
       sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
       or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
       location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
       *** extconf.rb failed ***
       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
       libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
       need configuration options.
       Provided configuration options:
       --with-opt-dir
       --without-opt-dir
       --with-opt-include
       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
       --with-opt-lib
       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
       --with-make-prog
       --without-make-prog
       --srcdir=.
       --curdir
       --ruby=/tmp/build_3e5ff6a8-f774-4699-b590-b197eacde04d/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby
       --with-sqlite3-dir
       --without-sqlite3-dir
       --with-sqlite3-include
       --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
       --with-sqlite3-lib
       --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
       --enable-local
       --disable-local
       Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_3e5ff6a8-f774-4699-b590-b197eacde04d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_3e5ff6a8-f774-4699-b590-b197eacde04d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
       Installing sass (3.2.13)
       Installing sprockets (2.10.1)
       Installing pg (0.15.1)
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.8), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.8'` succeeds before bundling.
       Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
       Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Using minitest (4.7.5)
       Using atomic (1.1.14)
       Using tzinfo (0.3.38)
       Using builder (3.1.4)
       Using erubis (2.7.0)
       Using rack (1.5.2)
       Installing multi_json (1.8.4)
       Using polyglot (0.3.3)
       Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
       Using arel (4.0.1)
       Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
       Using execjs (2.0.2)
       Using thor (0.18.1)
       Using hike (1.2.3)
       Using json (1.8.1)
       Installing mime-types (1.25.1)
       Using bundler (1.5.2)
       Using tilt (1.4.1)
       Installing i18n (0.6.9)
       Using rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
       Installing rake (10.1.1)
       Installing rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.2)
       Using thread_safe (0.1.3)
       Using rack-test (0.6.2)
       Using treetop (1.4.15)
       Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Installing uglifier (2.1.1)
       Using rdoc (3.12.2)

       Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

       /tmp/build_3e5ff6a8-f774-4699-b590-b197eacde04d/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       checking for sqlite3.h... no
       sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
       or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
       location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
       *** extconf.rb failed ***
       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
       libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
       need configuration options.

       Provided configuration options:
       --with-opt-dir
       --without-opt-dir
       --with-opt-include
       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
       --with-opt-lib
       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
       --with-make-prog
       --without-make-prog
       --srcdir=.
       --curdir
       --ruby=/tmp/build_3e5ff6a8-f774-4699-b590-b197eacde04d/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby
       --with-sqlite3-dir
       --without-sqlite3-dir
       --with-sqlite3-include
       --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
       --with-sqlite3-lib
       --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
       --enable-local
       --disable-local


       Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_3e5ff6a8-f774-4699-b590-b197eacde04d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_3e5ff6a8-f774-4699-b590-b197eacde04d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
       Installing sass (3.2.13)
       Installing sprockets (2.10.1)
       Installing pg (0.15.1)
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.8), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.8'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !     
 !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:calm-castle-9869.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:calm-castle-9869.git'
```

And also:

```
flashbag@netbook:~/rails/first$ ls -al
total 80
drwxr-xr-x 14 flashbag flashbag 4096 Jan 18 12:57 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 flashbag flashbag 4096 Jan 18 12:05 ..
drwxr-xr-x  8 flashbag flashbag 4096 Jan 18 02:48 app
drwxr-xr-x  2 flashbag flashbag 4096 Jan 18 02:48 bin
drwxr-xr-x  2 flashbag flashbag 4096 Jan 18 03:19 .bundle
drwxr-xr-x  5 flashbag flashbag 4096 Jan 18 12:57 config
-rw-r--r--  1 flashbag flashbag  154 Jan 18 02:48 config.ru
drwxr-xr-x  2 flashbag flashbag 4096 Jan 18 11:52 db
-rw-r--r--  1 flashbag flashbag  256 Jan 18 12:41 Gemfile
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root     2498 Jan 18 12:41 Gemfile.lock
drwxr-xr-x  8 flashbag flashbag 4096 Jan 18 03:32 .git
-rw-r--r--  1 flashbag flashbag  466 Jan 18 02:48 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x  4 flashbag flashbag 4096 Jan 18 02:48 lib
drwxr-xr-x  2 flashbag flashbag 4096 Jan 18 02:52 log
drwxr-xr-x  3 flashbag flashbag 4096 Jan 18 03:32 public
-rw-r--r--  1 flashbag flashbag  250 Jan 18 02:48 Rakefile
-rw-r--r--  1 flashbag flashbag  478 Jan 18 02:48 README.rdoc
drwxr-xr-x  8 flashbag flashbag 4096 Jan 18 02:48 test
drwxr-xr-x  6 flashbag flashbag 4096 Jan 18 02:52 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  3 flashbag flashbag 4096 Jan 18 02:48 vendor
flashbag@netbook:~/rails/first$ grep 'sqlite' ./ -r
./.gitignore:/db/*.sqlite3
./.gitignore:/db/*.sqlite3-journal
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Weird, it's trying to build SQLite server-side I think. Possibly you've required a gem that needs SQLite?

Comment: My Gemfile.lock http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/6787668/

Comment: Huh. Weird. Time for me to wave my "I don't do Rails" wand and run away screaming into the night.